# I'm trying to use java to run a Terraria dedicated console server but there are some problems

Tags: java, multithreading, server, process, io

I want to realize some functions to automatically control the server. For instance, there's a command of Terraria dedicated server "Time" which shows the current time in game. I want to use another function dawn to reset the time at 12:00 AM in the game. So, I need to handle the input and output of the console server. To realize it, I'm using getRuntime() and I create 3 threads for the console server: inputstream, outputstream and errstream.
Here is my code for creation of the server process.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String path="F:\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Terraria\\TerrariaServer.exe";
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
        Thread errThread=new Thread(new ErrorCatcher(p.getErrorStream()));
        Thread readThread=new Thread(new Reader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))));
        Thread writeThread=new Thread(new Sender(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()))));
        errThread.start();
        readThread.start();
        writeThread.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
```

When directly running the server, it should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBMMk.png)

But after running it in the java:

```
- Terraria Server v1.4.0.5
   
1       Boss Training 
2       Depths of Indignity 
3       Fraternity of Gel
   
4       Powerful Defecation 
5       Sule 
6       The Dank Lake 
n       New World d
   <number> Delete World
```

There are no such words "Choose World" and the process stops here. Process doesn't end and looks like gets into an endless loop. When entering some instructions to the server, there are not any responses. Then, I found there are 2 subprocesses under the main process when running the server, one is called "Terraria.exe" and another is "conhost.exe". When I use Task manager to detroy the Terraria.exe, the words "Choose World" appears but when sending commands, it shows the "java.io.IOException: Broken pipe". I guess that terraria.exe is the real server process and the conhost.exe is just a controler to show output and get input.
After that I added configrations of server to make the server directly start without choosing some options in the console.
Here is the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String path="cmd /c F:\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Terraria\\TerrariaServer.exe -config F:\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Terraria\\config1.txt";
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
        Thread errThread=new Thread(new ErrorCatcher(p.getErrorStream()));
        Thread readThread=new Thread(new Reader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))));
        Thread writeThread=new Thread(new Sender(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()))));
        errThread.start();
        readThread.start();
        writeThread.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
```

It works well, here are some information of the output:

```
Terraria Server v1.4.0.5

Listening on port 7777
Type 'help' for a list of commands.

: Server started
```

It looks like the server is running normally and I tried to play in the server, everything is ok.
But, still no responses when entering some instructions.
Here is the code of 3 threads(read,write and error):

read:

```
public static class Reader implements  Runnable {
        BufferedReader br;
        Reader(BufferedReader br)
        {
            this.br=br;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String line="";
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    line=br.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(line!=null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

err:

```
public static class ErrorCatcher implements  Runnable{
        InputStream error;
        ErrorCatcher(InputStream error)
        {
            this.error=error;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) {

                    System.out.println("" + error.read());

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

write:

```
public static class Sender implements Runnable{
        BufferedWriter bw;
        Sender(BufferedWriter bw)
        {
            this.bw=bw;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String cmd;
            while(true)
            {
                try{
                    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    cmd = bufferRead.readLine();
                    if(cmd.equals("quit"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    bw.write(cmd+"\n");
                    bw.flush();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't konw where the problem is. It seems like server can be controled by programm in this way. I also had an idea to get the subprocess of server - conhost.exe because I thought the problem is in the terraria.exe. But I didn't find the way to get the suprocess from its parent.

Comment: The thread will stop if it throws an exception, you can use thread.run () to debug what the error is happening.

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't show anything. Actually, the thread did not stop or crash but just stayed there and when debugging it, it showed "The application is running".